# I cant recognize object with opencv 3.4 in python. The problem is about command of cap.read()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video

I am working on object recognition in python. I cant import the frames from camera.

When i use the command of `cap.read()`, it returns `None` according to variable explorer. But when i wrote the code first time, this line didnt has a problem. Instead of this problem, ı have an other problem in the line which is `cv2.matchTemplate()`. This problem was about size of variables. So, i suspect my last error is not about the code, its kinda structural problem. How can i solve these problems?

```python
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

obj = cv2.imread("telefon.jpg",0)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    w,h = obj.shape
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,obj,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

I expected this code has not a error. But it returns me that error message:

```python
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: OpenCV(3.4.1) 
C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11147: 
error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor"
```

Comment: Most likely `VideoCapture` didn't connect to a camera successfully (you don't really validate that anywhere in your code). Hard to say why, maybe there isn't one connected, or it might be already used by some other application...